# How to upload .mp4 video to S3 bucket using node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

Below is the Rest API to upload the video to S3,unable to play the video by downloading as players throwing invalid file format.

app.post('/insert-video', async(req, res) => {

```
const {
    data,
    name: fileName,
    size: fileSize,
    type: fileType
} = req.body

// ASW code start
const base64data = new Buffer(data, 'binary');

let params = {
    Bucket: "uploadvidoe",
    Key: fileName,
    ContentType: fileType,
    Body: base64data
};
try {
    let uploadPromise = await new AWS.S3().putObject(params).promise();
    console.log("Successfully uploaded data to bucket");
} catch (e) {
    console.log("Error uploading data: ", e);
}
```

});

Comment: The problem is when you try to reproduce or upload?

Comment: Invalid file format could be due multiple reasons. To debug this issue first, go to the s3 account and folder and try playing it within S3 player. This will tell you if you uploaded correctly. It could be the case where the upload isn't complete and you are trying to download it. Could you please give more info about your console log and what does S3 tell you?

Comment: First of all you have to work out if what you uploaded to S3 is the same as the original video file. Upload it, then download it from S3 using the awscli and then compare the two files. If they're different then chances are that your code didn't actually upload the video file correctly. Perhaps you code truncated the file or encoded it incorrectly for the putObject() call.

Comment: On trying i'm gettingcould you please share code snippet for uploading .mp4 video in S3 bucket.

Comment: On trying i'm getting "this file isnt playable, that might be because
the file type is unsupported, file extensio
is in correct"                                                                                                                COULD you please share code snippet for uploading .mp4 video to S3 and retrieving.

Comment: Use CloudFront to play the videos

Comment: do u find the fix for this ?